# Take picture in non-activity class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I want to take picture in an non-activity class. However I get error: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference. Here is my code:

**MainAcvitity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Print myprint = new Print();
    myprint.Picture();
}
```

**Print.java**

```
public class Print {
private static final String TAG = "Secret";
Context context;

public void Picture() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    ((Activity) this.context).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    Log.v(TAG, "I took a picture.");
}
}
```

I don't know what goes wrong. Can you tell me why this happens and how can I fix it? I don't want my Print class to be an Activity class. I know how how to take picture if Print is an Activity class. 0.0

Comment: attribute `context` is null. You should initialize it.

Comment: @Christopher It works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your context is null. You haven't init it yet.

If you want to create a class to open your camera, try this:

```
public class Print{
    private static final String TAG = "Secret";
    private Context context;
    private File photoCaptured;

    public Print(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void openCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
        String fileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp;

        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            photoCaptured = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    fileName + ".jpg");
        } else {
            String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myDirectory";
            //create folder
            File folder = new File(dir); //folder name
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }

            //create file
            photoCaptured = new File(dir, fileName + ".jpg");
        }

        Uri temUri = Uri.fromFile(photoCaptured);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, temUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            ((AppCompatActivity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `MainActivity`, init `Print` and use it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Print myprint = new Print(this);
    myprint.openCamera();
}
```

For your question, just init your `Print` class and it will work. (Just for your case only, but this is not the best approach!!!)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Print myprint = new Print(this);
    myprint.Picture()
}
```

Comment: where is the onAtivityResult here? How will I get the intent data back?